# How to import a pod dependency into your own Framework Project that is inside your main project in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Before anything else, I have been searching for a similar question with an appropriate answer but failed.

1. [How to build an iOS Framework with a dependency on another without creating an Umbrella Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37146524/how-to-build-an-ios-framework-with-a-dependency-on-another-without-creating-an-u) --> Answer was from the original poster but not really detailed.
2. [How to add a framework inside another framework (Umbrella Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681435/how-to-add-a-framework-inside-another-framework-umbrella-framework) ---> Question is about developing an Umbrella framework which is not recommended.

So I have a main project called **TimeIn** and I have dragged into that project a framework project called **GPKit** (my own), however, there is a class in the **GPKit** project that is dependent to **Alamofire** framework used by the main project **TimeIn**. Question again is: is it possible to share the **TimeIn**'s Alamofire framework (pod) to the **GPKit** framework?

**Whole Project Structure**

[image]

**GPKit**'s Project Settings

[image]

Comment: you can add the alamofire framework as a subdependency in your GPKit.

Comment: And how do I do that? Is it wrong if I add Alamofire.framework in the Link Binary with Libraries of my GPKit?

Comment: in your  podspec file of GPKit

Comment: So I should integrate cocoapods as well to the GPKit even though the main project TimeIn has already one?

Comment: is your GPKit contains any Podspec file ..?

Comment: Should one expect a framework project to have a Podspec file without installing cocoapods to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145112/discussion-between-anil-kumar-and-prettyitgirl-com).

Comment: How do I up this question?

Comment: can we do this without using CocoaPods